# How to edit forms created using solspace freeform pro composer template in sublime

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have just started using solspace freeform pro. I created a contact form with about 30 fields in it using the composer template of freeform pro module in expressionengine. I did this by creating the fields I need and them in the composer I just dragged and dropped them. Now I want to add some conditional statements to the fields such that selecting a checkbox shows some fields else those fields remain hidden. I want to edit the code for this form in sublime but am unable to locate the file. Can someone please help me where to find the file in my FTP client software. I am also unable to figure out how to put this form on my website. 
I am sorry if this question is too basic but I have been trying to find something on google for past few days but have no luck. Any help in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If using the form tag and outputting using the all [form fields loop](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#freeform_all_form_fields) isn't an option, to get what you need to do done you may have to resort to Javascript hiding/showing. That's my understanding. When I need that flexibility I resort to that all form fields loop so I have full control of the markup.

Comment: That makes sense but to do that I will need to get access to the code of that form, and am unable to find that file. Can you please tell me were to find the file so I can open it in sublime and add some Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was confused earlier but after reading the docs carefully on the solspace website it was much clear. I just created a template in expressionengine, added the freeform tags and used the fields created in freeform module. It works perfectly now. I also used jquery for hiding/showing some fields.